# Finding the laplace transform of a wave?

Tags: laplace-transform

I was going through the solutions of a past paper and came across this question where it is asked to determine the laplace transform of a transient waveform. I'm a bit confused with how it balances the waves and getting 10000 slope. Can anybody shed some light on it?

[image]

The equation obtained is as follows

$$i(t) = (5000 slope ramp at t=0) -(10000 slope ramp at t=2)+ (5000 slope ramp at t=4)($$ 
$$ I(s) = \frac{5000}{s^2}(1-2e^{-0.002s}+e^{-0.004s})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interval [0, 0.002], the signal has a slope of \$100/0.002= 50000\$. Then in [0.002, 0.004] its \$-50000 \$ and in [0.004, \$\infty\$] it is \$0\$.

Now let us try to represent the original signal as a sum of ramp (shifted ramp) signals. *ie.,*

$$ y = y_1 + y_2+y_3$$

**Interval 1, [0, 0.002]**: The slope is 50000 so a ramp with slope 5000 is required. So 
$$y_1 = 50000t$$

**Interval 2, [0.002, 0.004]**: The slope here is -50000. So another ramp (\$y_2\$) starting at \$t=0.002\$ should be added here to make the slope = \$-50000\$.

$$y = 50000t+y_2$$

Taking the derivative on both sides

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 50000 +\frac{dy_2}{dt} =-50000 $$
$$\frac{dy_2}{dt} =-100000$$

So the slope of \$y_2 = -100000\$ and

$$y_2 = -100000(t-0.002)$$

**Interval 3, [0.004, \$\infty\$]**: following the similar analysis,

$$y_3 = 50000(t-0.004)$$

Then,

$$y = 50000t -100000(t-0.002) + 50000(t-0.004)$$

Taking Laplace transform,
$$Y(s) = \frac{50000}{s^2}(1-2e^{-0.002s}+e^{-0.004s})\tag1$$

**EDIT:** Calculating Laplace transform obtained in (1)

If \$F(s)\$ is the laplace transform of \$f(t)\$, then by property of Laplace transform,
$$f(t)\Leftrightarrow F(s) $$
$$f(t-t_0)\Leftrightarrow e^{-t_0s}F(s) $$

We know that:
$$t \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{s^2}$$
Using the property mentioned above,
$$(t-0.002) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{s^2}\times e^{-0.002s}$$
$$(t-0.004) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{s^2}\times e^{-0.004s}$$

Comment: Can u please explain a bit about how you converted the y(t) to Y(s)? I can understand how the first term (tranformation of 50,000t) was obtained but I can't understand the next two terms.

Comment: I was not aware of a time shifting property before. Got it (y)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to define \$f(t)\$ as a piecewise function

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{100}{0.002}\cdot t,&0\le t\le 2\cdot 10^{-3}\\
100-\frac{100}{0.002}\cdot (t-2),&2\cdot 10^{-3}<t\le 4\cdot 10^{-3}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Then with the definition of the Laplace transform

$$F(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt$$

you just split the integral and use the top expression in (1) in the interval \$[0,2]\$, and the bottom expression in the interval \$[2,4]\$.

Another way to solve such problems is to compute the Laplace transform of the derivative of \$f(t)\$, which is a piecewise constant function. The derivative of \$f(t)\$ can be written using the step function \$u(t)\$:

$$f'(t)=k\cdot[u(t)-2u(t-2)+u(t-4)]\tag{2}$$

where \$k=100/0.002\$, and where I've used units of milliseconds. From (2) you can immediately write down the result by noting that the Laplace transform of \$u(t-t_0)\$ is \$e^{-st_0}/s\$. As soon as you have the Laplace transform of \$f'(t)\$, you just need to divide by \$s\$ to obtain the Laplace transform of \$f(t)\$.

And, by the way, \$100/0.002=50000\$, and not \$5000\$.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't call your first method the easiest way - it's the most obvious way, but it's pretty messy and unnecessary.

Comment: @Kynit: It's easier than that cancelling ramp business in the OP. I meant easy in terms of defining \$f(t)\$. The easiest solution to the problem is the one with the step functions.

Comment: The "cancelling ramp business" is exactly the same as your step functions. You just wrote the derivatives instead of the functions.

Comment: @Kynit: I know that, but it's exactly the derivatives that make it clearer and less error prone. But it's up to everybody to choose their favorite method.

Comment: Meh. The way I learned it, time shifts are simple and seem like they require one less step. To each their own. Take a +1 for your trouble.

Comment: @Kynit: Thanks, but one last thing: I do use time shifts because they're simple, I just use time-shifted steps instead of ramps, but it is really a matter of taste. If a function is defined as piecewise powers of \$t\$, then you can always use this method, and you don't need to worry about the transform of \$t^n\$ (including the correct factor). But I obviously agree with 'to each their own'.

Comment: right, but then you have to worry about the transform of \$nt^{n-1}\$... Oh well. It's all the same in the end.

Comment: @Kynit: No, I take as many derivatives as necessary to get a piecewise constant function. Then I just need to divide by the corresponding power of \$s\$ to get the transform of the original function.